# How can I correctly input a List<List<Integer>> in my main method?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a function that takes data from a 2D array and stores it in a Hashmap. I just want to know that how can I input a 2D int array correctly in my main function. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Sorted {

    public static void countSort(List<List<Integer>> inputData) {
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> dataAsMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(List<Integer> row : inputData) {
            Integer id = row.get(0); 
            Integer item = row.get(1);
            List<Integer> rowInMap = dataAsMap.get(item);
            if (rowInMap == null) {
                rowInMap = new ArrayList<>();
                dataAsMap.put(item, rowInMap);
            }
       
            rowInMap.add(id);
        }
    }
 
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] newArray = {{ 1, 2, 3}, {101, 102, 103}};
        Arrays.countSort(newArray);
    }    
}
```

Unless you haven't noticed already, this code wouldn't even compile. I believe that `[[1, 2, 3], [100, 101, 102]]` is indeed a 2D integer array but my issue is that I have no idea how to implement it in the `countsort()` function. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Start with getting your code to compile...  have a look at https://www.educba.com/2d-arrays-in-java/ and do something like this: `public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[][] newArray = {{ 1, 2, 3}, {101, 102, 103}};
  ArrayMain.countSort(newArray);
 }
`  with your method signature of `public static void countSort(int[][] array)`

Comment: I realized that my function is a void, which is why I couldn't simply just call it as I did. I've tried to look over it and implemented some changes as u said. I have edited my response accordingly as well.  However, there still seems to be a compilation error, in particular the Arrays.countSort(newArray) part. Sorry to disturb you but can you please let me know what changes should I make, if u can?

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what you are trying to do.  As I understand it you are trying to change a 2d array of integers into a Hashmap keyed on an int with the value being a list of ints???

Comment: I'm trying to take in a List<List<Integer>> as an input in my countSort method and return it as a Hashmap (which should be done). My issue is in the main function. I'm trying to input a List<List<Integer>> but I do not know what to do for it to at least compile

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a multi dimensional array list then try with below code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add(1); list1.add(2); list1.add(3);
        
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add(101); list2.add(102); list2.add(103);
        
        List<List<Integer>>  main = new ArrayList<>();
        main.add(list1);
        main.add(list2);
        
        Sorted.countSort(main);
}
```

In your main method final line,

```
Arrays.countSort(newArray);
```

I don't think this is correct. It should your class name.

Comment: when I try to run this code, nothing pops up. Is that what you get as well?

Comment: Yes, that is because of no any System.Out in the code. Please add print statements and check.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        int addable = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            List<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int j = addable; j <= addable + 3; j++) {
                innerList.add(j);
            }
            addable += 100;
            list.add(innerList);
        }

        System.out.println(list);
```

which will output

`[[1, 2, 3, 4], [101, 102, 103, 104], [201, 202, 203, 204]]`